# How to Make Multi User Objects Single User?

Tags: objects, linked-data

I duplicated a few objects with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and now I want to apply some modifiers to them, however I can't, because they are multi-user objects.

I tried <kbd>U</kbd> *> Objects* but I still can't apply the modifier.

How to make multi user objects single user?

Comment: check this video if your still not having any luck... it worked for me... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwmdbMsnANw

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Blender 2.8+ it's in the 3D View main menu

*Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object + Data > Selected Object* (or *All* if you need that)

[image: Blender 2.82 Screenshot:]

Answer (score 49):

Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Objects and Data*. Then apply your modifier. Using just *Object* will make the object a new, separate datablock for the mesh (but will ignore modifiers). However, using *Object and Data* will make both the objects mesh and it's modifiers a new, separate datablock.

Comment: Oh hey, I was about to post asking how to do this in bulk because I thought I'd tried this and had it not work for me... but now it does! The magic of searching. ... Also I think the 'object' part is only relevant for objects that are in more than once scene, since there's no way for different objects in the same scene to share a modifier stack.

Comment: Why is it that when I hit the space bar and enter "make single user", select the only option in the list I only get options "Selected objects" and "all"?While pressing "u" gives "Objects and Data" as option as well and the option list has the header "Make single user".

Answer (score 30):

Go into Data properties, and small number button next to the data name. This will create a single user copy of the data.

Note that you have to make only the data single-user.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text* to convert it to a mesh. This will apply the modifier for all instances of the mesh. This means you can get just one instance looking exactly how you want it, use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command, and it will be applied to all the meshes.

Comment: Useful trick to know, but not very helpful if I only want to apply one modifier to one object..