# How to unlink a material only from a linked object?

Tags: materials, objects, linked-data, scene

I've created a second scene with a linked object but want to replace the materials on those objects only in the second scene.

Nothing happens if I choose the material in the outliner and choose unlink. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's a mesh object, it might be that your material is linked to the mesh (the data), not the object. Try this structure: Two different objects, both of which use the same mesh. The materials are linked to the objects instead of the mesh. Then you have an object identical in shape, but different in color.

You can set the type of link to the right of the material name.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I set the Materials to link to the object rather than the data and then did Scene copy "Link Object Data" and I was able to change the material and leave the rest of the object alone.

Comment: One is glad to be of service.

Comment: So _that's_ what that switch does! Very good to know, thanks.