# Unlinking object

Tags: materials, linked-data

I duplicated some meshes to make a stack of blocks by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. When I apply material for one mesh, it will also be copied to the linked meshes. I know I can use <kbd>U</kbd> and then 'Material and tex'. But what will happen when I do the other options:

- Object
- Object & Data
- Object & Data & Material & tex
- Object animation

Which one is recommended for making a rigid body simulation with a stack of blocks that will flip over? Thanks :)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/how-to-unlink-a-material-only-from-a-linked-object, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

you can have different materials for instance if you choose to link the material to the object, not to the data. I'm not sure I understand well the question but for having not linked mesh and material you can also do :
make single user /Object & Data & Material & tex