# How can I make two duplicated object's material's independently editable?

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, linked-data

I duplicated an object, but now when I try to adjust the color, or texture to one object, it automatically adjusts it's sister's color too. How do I disconnected that relation?

Comment: related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user

Comment: I went into Data properties, and there was no  small number button next to the data name as the link above states. Only the letter F.  

How do I make it a "data single-user."...?

Comment: Go to second object and in materials tab press the - button

Comment: Now that was easy! Thanks a billion! I'm on a deadline and you just saved my bacon!

Comment: This is related to blender's concept of Datablocks  https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/datablocks.html .  Datablocks (such as meshes, materials, and animations) can be shared by multiple users.  Object datablocks can be shared by multiple scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the materials tab, and click on the number that appears next to the material's name. This will make it a single user, by duplicating the material, basically meaning that they can be edited separately.

[image]