# How do you change the colors of 2 objects with nodes?

Tags: node-editor

[image][image]when I press an object and go to the nodes and get finished with the color and I want to go to an other object and change the color from the nodes but it won't work it only stays for the first object?

Comment: Can you upload some photos of node setups, etc. and possibly a .blend file as well? Otherwise your problem is too broad to be answered specifically. We need details so that we may provide the most effective solution as possible.

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35315/how-can-i-make-two-duplicated-objects-materials-independently-editable

Comment: how do you get it to where each object will have its own pair of compositing nodes? because as you can see in the pics i choose different objects and the compositing node stays the same for that one object, meaning that can you have only one compositing node over all?

Comment: I believe that you may be just misunderstanding the use of Nodes. You are in the Compositor section, which is a post process based on the last render, (not so much your selected object(s)). If you were to take the same approach with the Materials Section of the Node Editor (its the target looking icon just left of the **Use Nodes** checkbox, that will begin to react according to your selection of objects in the 3D scene, just not in post production.

Comment: To see the changes you make in the materials section, you will need to change your display type in the 3D editor to something like Rendered / Material / Texture - **NOT** Solid or wireframe.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP said that this is what helped, then the answer to this question is to use material nodes, not the compositor nodes for the purpose of changing material properties with context sensitivity being per selection in the 3D viewport.

Albeit, the compositor nodes can definitely be used to change visual properties of everything (with a high degree of power and with a great myriad of approaches), in this case I believe that my prior statement is the answer for this question.

For whatever the reason may be (newness to the software, lack of experience in node editing, etc...), I imagine it to be true that this particular question would be very hard for a user at a beginning level of understanding to articulate.  This being said, I hope that this helps somebody else who may be searching for the same/similar solution in the future gain good information; even though it may be hard for them to describe.