# Is there a way to change the emission number of a particle system, without affecting the emission number of the mesh it's separated from?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, particles, linked-data

I have a mesh with a particle system.

[image]

I then split the mesh (using <kbd>P</kbd> > "separate by selection") and have 2 objects with 2 particle systems.

[image]

However, I like each particle system to have a different emission number, so I select <kbd>U</kbd> > "Object & Data, Materials + Tex".

I can then remove the particle system from one mesh (and the other remains), but I can't alter the emission number of one without affecting the emission of its counterpart. Is there another way to separate data I don't know about?

[image]

**Current Solution:**

There is a workaround if I delete one system, then re-add it with the appropriate number, but I'm wondering if there's a better way already in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is really a solution; it's not a workaround.

The reason you can't change one without changing the other is because they are the same particle system, just used in two different places. This is just like when you use the same material in two different places; when you change the color of one, it changes in both places.

Deleting the particle system and making a new one with new settings is one way to "unlink" the two. Another way is to make the second particle system a "single user copy." Do this by clicking the number that's next to the name of the particle system. This will keep all of the original settings, but make it into a separate system so that you can change it's settings without affecting the other one.

I hope that helps!

Comment: The information in this other question is also useful, but that might not be obvious: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user

Comment: Right! I knew there was something I was forgetting, thank-you