# Multiple objects being edited in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I've tried googling this but I don't even know how to word it. I'm fairly new to blender and i've just been using it to edit some models slightly. I've come across a problem on some of the model. [image]

This model was taken from a .x3d file I've imported and wish to edit, whenever I select any of those cylinders and tab into edit mode, they all tab into edit mode. Anything I do to one, effects the others, and this is undesirable. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

Thanks a lot

Let me know if there is anything else you need me to add.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user , they share a mesh.

Comment: When duplicating make sure you uncheck linked box which appears right after you duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they have linked data, they share the same mesh and whatsoever you are doing to one applies to the others. So either press U and select `Object & Data`

[image]
or press the number that shows how many objects share the data (on the right in the red circle)