# Editing one of the objects without affecting the other two when placed in scene using asset browser

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, asset-browser

I have 3 copies of the same object placed in my scene from the asset browser how can I edit one of the objects without affecting the other two.  I tried making it **as single user** but it says **not yet implemented** Any workaround?

I'm using Blender 3.01

[image: img1]

I try and extrude the face of just one of the objects and it extrudes similar faces on each object placed in the scene from the asset manager.

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

I tried "UN-linking" the object but it disappeared see animation below

[image: an1]

Comment: Click “unlink.” I think that will localize the data to the object. PS: It’s “affect” here, not “effect.”

Comment: @TheLabCat Thanks but that didn't work I added an animation to the question showing what happens when I click "Unlink"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make Multi User Objects Single User?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user) (the specific shortcut you're using seems not implemented yet but both the menu and F3 > typing "make single user" should work or click on the number next to the mesh name in the mesh property)

Comment: @Gorgious Yes that fixed it thanks, strange that they added the menu item but didn't add the code in the back-end (since it's already there)